# Sound not working, ALSAMIXER not working

Tags: 14.04, alsa, realtek, soundcard, hda-intel

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and when i booted it the sound was working. But it wasn't working the way it does on Windows 7, like in it there is a feature for me to use Dolby Technology to create really nice sound. On Ubuntu, it just really bad just 'treble?" and no bass. It doesn't even use the subwoofer present on my laptop.

So I tried installing [this](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=24&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false) [extracted, complied, install make]. Used the Linux version. It just completely broke the sound system on my laptop. NO more sound or anything.

I did this too from a thread I found,

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils
sudo apt-get install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils
```

It didn't to anything. Now I ran this command

```
 wget -O alsa-info.sh http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh && bash alsa-info.sh --upload
```

and [this](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=fd16e63fb4a1a7b9196240b3e1c8aaec78a0dd2e) is its output.

My laptop is Qomsio F 50-126 with builtin Subwooder and two speakers and running Ubuntu 14.04.

The [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQOY1.jpg) of the Sound Setting Window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dolby thing is done by software emulation in the Windows driver.
No Linux driver will have it.

The sound drivers are part of the kernel.
Reinstall (or update to a newer version, if possible) the kernel package (`linux`).

Comment: Dolby thing is definitely not emulation because it actually activates one of the laptop hardware component. Kernel version I have right now is 3.13.0-24-generic. I'm pretty sure its not not the kernel problem but instead me removing one of the audio driver setting.

Comment: What hardware component? And the Realtek installer *did* change the kernel modules.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to run system update and hopefully it reinstall the sound driver and fixes it. The hardware is a subwoofer under the laptop. The computer is actually 2.1 Stereo system. Its definitely not emulation like emulate sounds as if in a auditorium, home theater, zoo etc

Comment: Updating fixed it but I still miss my sub woofer functionality.

Comment: This is me, I just gave up.